# Swift Firebase - Convert database snapshot into an array

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a groups reference in firebase that looks like this:
[image: database]

I'm having trouble converting the list of members into an array of strings in my app.

I'm fetching the data like so:

```swift
//Reference to each group
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("groups").child(snapshot.key)

//Get the group data from the reference
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (groupSnap) in
    //Cast data as dictionary [String:Any]
    if let dictionary = groupSnap.value as? [String: Any] {
        //Parse each group object
        if let group = Group.parse(snapshot.key, dictionary) {
            groups.insert(group, at: 0)
        }

        //Escape with group array
        complete(groups)
    }
})
```

And currently parsing the data without the members:

```swift
static func parse(_ key: String, _ data: [String:Any]) -> Group? {
    let name = data["name"] as! String
    let category = data["category"] as! String
    let owner = data["owner"] as! String

    return Group(id: key, name: name, category: Group.Category(rawValue: category)!, ownerId: owner, members: nil)
}
```

How would I turn the members list into an array of strings for my group object?

Comment: it doesn't look like an array, it looks like a dictionary `[String:Bool]`

Comment: I would like to create an array with just the keys, not the booleans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// example data
let data = [
    // "name": ...
    // "category": ...
    // "owner": ...
    "members": [
        "member1": true,
        "member2": false,
        "member3": true,
        "member4": true
    ]
]

// grabbing the members element like you do in your parse function
let members = data["members"] as! [String: Bool]

let membersAsListOfStrings = Array(members.keys)
print(membersAsListOfStrings) // -> ["member4", "member1", "member3", "member2"]

let filteredMembersAsListOfStrings = Array(members.filter { $0.value }.keys)
print(filteredMembersAsListOfStrings) // -> ["member4", "member3", "member1"]
```

You're looking for the `.keys` attribute. I believe all dictionaries in Swift have this. This code ran for me fine in a playground.